# PHP::Imagick Creating a Temp FIle from A Composite Image, for displaying through <img> Tag

Tags: php, imagick

Is it possible to create a temp file server side for viewing an image?

I've some images & they're displayed from server but I want to have them watermarked... Found out about the Imagick Class, used composite... It can be viewed when sent as header but I need it somehow visible  for the  tag.

I don't want to uses 'write image' & create a new image from the composited image. I'm trying to use it as client Side thing (I'm not familiar with JS... Yes, I'll look into it but need an alternative till then).

Another alternative that I'm aware of is I should control that WHILE uploading the images but I've already uploaded quite a few so...
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the function that generates your image as a `src` attribute for the `<img />` tag?

I don't know exactly how your code is, but I am thinking the end result could be something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image_headers); ?>">
```

You basically output the headers inside the image `src` as a base64 encoded string.

What you should keep in mind is that you should adjust the `image/jpeg` type to the corresponding type of your image.

For example:

- For JPG, JPEG files it would be `image/jpeg`
- For PNG files it would be `image/png`
- For WEBP files it would be `image/webp`

And of course the encoded string should be an image of the corresponding format.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. I'll give it a try in a few & let you know if that works. Also, I'll share  the code as well.

Comment: So I updated the tag with the new code but it still outputs a bunch of gibberish text instead of the image

Comment: Could you update your question with the image generating code? The full function preferably. I'm a little blind here :)

Comment: I actually figured it out, I didn't understand what exactly you meant at first but I roamed around & got it. It works perfect now except for one thing. If I right click & open it in a new tab, it says the entire encoded base64 structure... If there's an alternative to rename it or so, as the source images... Here's the source code
https://stackoverflow.com/q/61419943/13168285

Comment: As far as I am aware you are not able to do this since the entire image is inside the src. It's not a generated file, it's literally the raw code of the image. If you need to be able to save it with a file name, you'd have to save the image file on your server and output that instead. Except for that, did my answer work  for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand. 
It also takes a long time because of running the entire code everytime.

Comment: Yes, what you could do is have a temp folder for generated images and check if a generated image with the same criteria exists.